# Formatted HD, forgot to back up a text file. How do I get it back?

Tags: hard-drive, data-recovery

I have already had the same problem before. On that ocasion, I found a program that could scan my entire HD for string pieces so I could recover it. Unfortunatelly I don't remember the name of the program. It had to access the HD data directly, normal searches won't get any data from the HD before formatting.

Comment: [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) does this kind of thing

Comment: Try this also: http://www.piriform.com/recuva